# How to specify bands to process rasters with gdal.Warp in Python?

Tags: python, gdal

I use Python to write scripts based on `gdal` library.

I want to specify which bands do I need to process with `gdal.Warp` and I use `gdal.WarpOptions()` parameter as mentioned in [API](https://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html#a9b60196e623b269e8f4905bf9e1792e2). But my PyCharm IDE says that there is no such option!

**How to specify which band to process using `gdal.Warp`?**

PyCharm's `gdal.WarpOptions()` pop-up menu:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "Python's gdal.wrap" or "Python's gdal.Warp" or "gdal.Warp in Python" in the title?

Comment: @Vince gdal.Warp Sorry i will edit the tittle.

Comment: There are warp.options and warp.warpoptions. The latter are the same as options available through -wo from gdalwarp https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html. Perhaps the tutorial in https://www.gdal.org/warptut.html can give some hints around the place that deals with `psWarpOptions->panSrcBands[0] = 1;` and `psWarpOptions->panDstBands[0] = 1;`.